# My own javascript class and addeventlistener template not working

Tags: javascript

So here I am experimenting with native javascript. What I am trying to achieve, but failed to do is to create some sort of shortcut for scenarios where I want to add an event listener to a div class.

Here I am trying to say: If the user clicked on a class then show an alert.

Why doesnt my code work?

```
function click(red){
    var source = document.getElementsByClassName(red);
        for (i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            source[i].addEventListener('click', err, false);
        }
    function err() { 
    var x = 0;
    }
}

if (click('red')) {
    alert('rrr');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y66wh26k/3/

Comment: `err` is your callback - there's no alert there.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y66wh26k/4/

Comment: @dave it works! Can you recommend any tutorial or book in order to gain more experience?

Comment: @Asperger: Javascript: The Good Parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `document.querySelectorAll` instead of `document.getElementsByClassName` because it is more versatile.

But the main issue is that your click function actually wasn't returning anything, so your `if(click('red'))` would never execute. As well, your callback for the event listener being added wasn't really doing anything. So what I've done is made a callback argument, then passed that to `addEventListener`.

```js
function click(selector, callback){
    var source = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = source.length-1; i >= 0; --i) {
        source[i].addEventListener('click', callback, false);
    }
}
click('.red', function() {
    alert('rrr');
});
```

```html
<div class='red'>xxx</div>
<div class='red'>xxx</div>
<div class='red'>xxx</div>
```